# Send a message to a channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a function that send messages, but it doesn't work because it's not inside

```
client.on('message', msg => {
```

How can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are there any errors that you can show us? Can you post the function you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

You can send messages from outside client.on('message'..., All you need is channel ID and then you can simply do:

```
const myChannel = client.channels.get('CHANNEL_ID');
myChannel.send(`your message here!`);
```

**EDIT**
You can use this inside a function by passing it as a parameter:

```
const myChannel = client.channels.get('CHANNEL_ID');
function myFunc(channel) {
  channel.send('MESSAGE');
}
```

Now you can call your function using myChannel:

```
myFunc(myChannel);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I have an error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Comment: Try doing console.log(myChannel); after defining myChannel to make sure that your channel id is correct. 
EDIT: define myChannel first then pass it into your function as a parameter and then you can use myChannel.send(`your message here!`); inside your function

Comment: When I do "console.log(myChannel);" it says "undefined", but I don't think I've wrote a wrong Channel ID

Comment: If possible please update your answer with a link to your code so I can assist you better. Channel ID is a 16 digit integer. You can find it by going to discord, enabling developer mode and then right clicking on channel > copy ID

Comment: "update your answer with a link to your code" What website?

Comment: @tspsims Please do not refer to an external website for your code: it's best to post the relevant code (such as your function, the way you get the channel and the way you call your function) in your question, so that everyone will be able to see it. You can find more info about it here: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`client.on("message")` is an event that will trigger each time a new message is sent in a channel the bot can see. (DMs included.)

To send a message to a channel id, first you have to find the channel using the `client.channels` collection.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client = new Discord.Client(); // Creating a new Discord Client.

Client.on("ready", () => {
  const Channel = Client.channels.get("your channel id"); // Searching the channel in the collection channels.
  if (!Channel) {
    return console.error("No channel found!"); // If the channels does not exist or the bot cannot see it, it will return an error.
  } else {
    return Channel.send("Your message to send here!"); // We found the channel. Sending a message to it.
  };
}); // Making sure the client is ready before sending anything.

Client.login("your bot token here"); // Logging into Discord with the bot's token.
```